# Dynamic loading of html controls in Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular7

I am working on data reporting solution in angular 7.

my app is going to host around 200+ reports and I want to make reusable components so I don't need to create 200+ component up front and in future, if we onboard a new report then no code changes are required.

The idea is...
1. Report Parameters and Spname will be stored in DB
2. Based on Report parameter, Report criteria section will be displayed.
3. User provide parameters value and click on generate button then request will be sent to REST services.
4. Rest services will fetch the data from DB based on Spname provided in report definition and give it back to angular app.

Report parameters examples like ...
`FreeText` => so users can input any string data
`Date` => to select a reporting date
`Multiselect` => to persent multi select drop down box
`singleselect` => to allow users to select only one value at a time.

The problem is every report is difference combination of these parameters and also parameters can be repeatable for given report like there could be a report where two dates are needed (to and from)  so cannot fix criteria structure.

Is there any way I can generate controls at run-time and display on component.
One way I can think of is Jquery. Not sure if this is the right way to achieve this goal.

Any sample code available for the same or any other approach for the same.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div>
                    <button class="ev-button" style="float: right;" type="button">Generate Report</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <app-report-criteria></app-report-criteria>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vl"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <app-report-data-display></app-report-data-display>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my code here is just dividing the screen into two section, criteria and data.
I need to do make app-report-criteria powerful enough to generate controls at run-time based on report criteria

Comment: First of all, drop the idea of using jQuery, not recommended. Secondly, show us your code, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Not using jQuery, just thinking this could be a way to achieve it.
I tried google for generating controls at runtime in angular but every where people mentioned this is not recommended.

Comment: and I don;t want to create 200+ component in my app to serve the same functionality

Comment: Whoever is voted my question negative... could you please explain what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule of thumb for Angular development, dont use jQuery with it.

A simple proof of concept for a template driver form:

In your compenent.js generate the array of parameters:

```
    var params = [
        { name: "from", type: "date", classes: 'calendar' },
        { name: "to", type: "date", classes: 'calendar' },
        { name: "number", type: "number", classes: '' },
    ]
```

Then in your component html you can

```
<div *ngFor="let param of params">
    <input type="{{param.type}}" name="{{param.name}}" class="{{param.classes}}" /> 
</div>
```

If you have a component for every parameter type you can instead do:

```
<div *ngFor="let param of params" [ngSwitch]="param.type">

    <FreeText *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [name]="param.name" ... ></FreeText>

    <Date *ngSwitchCase="'date'" [name]="param.name" ... ></Date>

    <Multiselect *ngSwitchCase="'multi-select'" [name]="param.name" ... ></Multiselect >

    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... this looks like what I need... Let me try and will get back to you...

Comment: Did you succeded?

Comment: Yes... I did... I have created component for each dynamic control. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you think my answer is good enough you should accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot it... marked it as accepted